# pragma warning( disable : 4700 ) not working in Visual Studio Express 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, warnings, pragma

Compiling the following code in Release configuration with SDL checks disabled:

```
#include <immintrin.h>

int main()
{
    const auto Set128Epi16 = []()
    {
#ifdef NDEBUG
#pragma warning( push )
#pragma warning( disable : 4700 )
            __m128i x = _mm_cmpeq_epi16( x,x );
            x = _mm_srli_epi16( x,15 );
            return _mm_slli_epi16( x,7 );
#pragma warning( pop )
#else
            __m128i x = _mm_setzero_si128();
            x = _mm_cmpeq_epi16( x,x );
            x = _mm_srli_epi16( x,15 );
            return _mm_slli_epi16( x,7 );
#endif
    };

    const auto xmm = Set128Epi16();

    return *xmm.m128i_i32;
}
```

Gives the following output:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: pragmatic, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>  main.cpp
1>  Generating code
1>e:\projects\pragmatic\pragmatic\main.cpp(10): warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'x' used
1>e:\projects\pragmatic\pragmatic\main.cpp(10): warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'x' used
1>e:\projects\pragmatic\pragmatic\main.cpp(10): warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'x' used
1>e:\projects\pragmatic\pragmatic\main.cpp(10): warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'x' used
1>e:\projects\pragmatic\pragmatic\main.cpp(10): warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'x' used
1>  Finished generating code
1>  pragmatic.vcxproj -> E:\Projects\pragmatic\Release\pragmatic.exe
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Why is the compiler ignoring my #pragma in this case. I have in the past successfully used this method to suppress the same warning code.

Comment: Why are you trying to compare the value of an uninitialised variable against itself? You do realise that has undefined behaviour? And basically no practical use as far as I can tell? Perhaps you could explain more about what you're actually trying to do here.

Comment: It is reported as an error in VS2015.  Appropriately, the arguments to _mm_cmpeq_epi16() are not initialized.  Pretty hard to guess what is intended here, x and x should be equal for any value :)

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet It is a fairly common trick used to load 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF into an xmm register. Think pxor xmm0,xmm0. The contents of the register have no impact on the result.

Comment: @HansPassant the SDL check code generation build option promotes it to an error.

Comment: @chili: The contents are unspecified and reading them has undefined behaviour. It doesn't matter that you don't care what that unspecified value "is": this could crash your computer, or open a wormhole to Krypton. Unspecified is not equal to unspecified; it is undefined. I can't stress that enough.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I copied this from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e.aspx

> For warning numbers in the range 4700-4999, which are the ones associated with code generation, the state of the warning in effect when the compiler encounters the open curly brace of a function will be in effect for the rest of the function. Using the warning pragma in the function to change the state of a warning that has a number larger than 4699 will only take effect after the end of the function. The following example shows the correct placement of warning pragmas to disable a code-generation warning message, and then to restore it.

So you probably need to put the pragma before the start of `main`, or maybe before the lambda would work, but I'm not sure about that.